# How can I switch from Google Authentication to Apple Authentication

Tags: iphone, google, two-factor-authentication

Android user here since my first phone, I finally decided to switch to an iPhone. What a wonderful choice.

I was able to switch to every Apple's services (passwords, mails, messages...) but I have one big problem : switch from "connect with a Google account" to "connect with an Apple account".

On every websites, every services I ever used in my life, everytime I was able to connect with my Google account, I connected with my Google account.

But the problem is mostly the 2FA. While it's inherent to Android phones, it's not well integrated to Apple. I have to open the Google App to get the notification to authorize the 2FA from my iPhone.

Unlike the Google 2FA, the Apple 2FA works like a charm on the iPhone. **Indeed**.

So I want to switch, on every websites, every services, everywhere I used my Google account to connect, to my Apple account.

I know I can go on every websites one by one, and try to link my Apple Account everywhere, but what a painful way to solve this issue. Nowaday, the transition from Google to Apple is very fluent, but I didn't find any answer to this particular problem.

Do you know how can I easily switch from Google authentication to Apple authentication ?

Comment: There is no way to do that. The app/website has to keep track of how their "local users" are mapped to the IdP users. There is no way to simply "switch all", you must explicitly tell to each app/website that your apple identity should be mapped in the same way as your google identity. From the app point of view the google identity & apple identity are 2 different users unless explicitly "merged"/"linked" together.

Answer (score 1):

If Google does not allow you to export the setup key, you cannot move it to Apple Password Manager, and you must re-set up each website.

If Google allows you to export the setup keys, you can enter them directly into Apple Password Manager and will start receiving OTP codes.

I know that 1Password and Apple Password Manager can both export the setup keys for OTP Auth, but I believe that Google makes it a lot more difficult.

Answer (score -1):

## 2FA

According to [MacRumors article](https://www.macrumors.com/2020/12/03/google-authenticator-ios-app-gains-export-accounts/) Google Authenticator allows account export for some time.
Sadly, I cannot confirm, I don't use their 2FA.

## Connect with Apple/Google

On this you are on your own - in most cases (for example you shouldn't hide your email with apple auth) the site will recognize your identifier and add the second authentication provider. You could have more control of this if a site provides connected accounts page (usually somewhere in profile) and connect their desired provider.

Comment: The second paragraph is hard to understand. How does this relate to the question and which specific steps should be taken to implement this to solve the problem the OP has?

Comment: @nohillside let me cite the start of the second paragraph: 'On this you are on your own', simply the migration of authorization providers is per site basis (without any standardized flow) - not possible to automate in any way - so it reinstates the OP's 'fears' that the migration is manual and painful process that can't be automated